# How to find out if a device is currently is use?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

In an effort to create a Linux installation script, I'd like to check if `/dev/sda` is currently in use by the Kernel, and exit if so. I guess this means finding out what partitions are associated to the device and see if any of them is mounted... am I right with my guess? Is it possible for a device to be in use without having a mounted partition? What's the best way I should make the test? This is what I've come up with until now:

```
if [ $(findmnt -no SOURCE | grep ^/dev/sda) ];
then
    echo 'Hard disk drive is already in use.'
    exit
fi
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if something accesses the partition/harddisk directly (f.e. `dd if=/dev/sda1 ...`).